# Strange behaviour of php array

Tags: php, apache

I have two servers. On one I have developed site and on other I should put the same site. Apache, php, mysql etc was set by two different people and I can't get access now to first person because he is on vacation.
There is rather strange problem there. I have a func like this:

```
public function self() 
{
    return preg_split("/\./", $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'])[0];
}
```

When I put a code with funcs like this (index of array of result of fucntion) it just shows me white list instead of site like it was a php syntax mistake.
I changed it to this:

```
public function self() 
{
    $res=preg_split("/\./", $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
    return $res[0];

}
```

And it works fine.
Anyone here familiar with such behavior? May be I should install something additional to php?
Of course I can replace all work with indexes like I did it here. But first, it takes some time, secondly I'm sure that there is much more easier solution. Advice me smth=)

Comment: just the check the php version in the two servers. Might be the issues with two different version of php

Comment: The second option is best practice for code according to standards.Use it.

Comment: Yep, the versions are different.

Comment: @SumanSingh can you link the standards you're talking about?